# Can I save the state of my viewModel that holds data for my fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android app dev,I want my fragment to store user information in a viewModel, yet that **model is accessed by other fragments**. The app runs well but I would like it to store the viewModel even if the app is destroyed. How can I save the state of my model?

This is my viewModel class (it starts with the package name):

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

/**
* This model is shared by related views.
* stores user name1 and name2 that prevents repetition in filling forms.
* stores data lost during configuration changes.
* stores data from the form.
* */
class SharedViewModel() : ViewModel() {

   private val _nameOne = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val nameOne: LiveData<String> = _nameOne

   private val _nameTwo = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val nameTwo: LiveData<String> = _nameTwo

   private val _emailAddress = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val emailAddress: LiveData<String> = _emailAddress

   private val _phoneNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val phoneNumber: LiveData<String> = _phoneNumber

   private val _nationalIdNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
   val nationalIdNumber: LiveData<String> = _nationalIdNumber

   fun saveUserData(
       nameA: String, nameB: String,
       emailA: String, phoneN: String,
       natId: String) {

       _nameOne.value = nameA
       _nameTwo.value = nameB
       _emailAddress.value = emailA
       _phoneNumber.value = phoneN
       _nationalIdNumber.value = natId
   }
}
```

This is the MainActivity class (it starts with the package name):

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import ke.co.qaizen.qaizencarrental.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

/**
* Main Activity and entry point for the app.
*/
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Thread.sleep(3)
        installSplashScreen()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Get the navigation host fragment from this Activity
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        // Instantiate the navController using the NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        // Make sure actions in the ActionBar get propagated to the NavController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)



    }


    /**
    * Enables back button support. Simply navigates one element up on the stack.
    */
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

And this is my fragment class (it also starts with the package name):

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import ke.co.qaizen.qaizencarrental.databinding.FragmentAccountBinding
import ke.co.qaizen.qaizencarrental.mainmodel.SharedViewModel


class AccountFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentAccountBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(false)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentAccountBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        sharedViewModel.nameOne.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { nameOne ->
            binding.userNameOne.text = nameOne
        }
        sharedViewModel.nameTwo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { nameTwo ->
            binding.userNameTwo.text = nameTwo
        }
        sharedViewModel.emailAddress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { emailAddress ->
            binding.userEmailAddress.text = emailAddress
        }
        sharedViewModel.phoneNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { phoneNumber ->
            binding.userPhoneNumber.text = phoneNumber
        }
        sharedViewModel.nationalIdNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { 
nationalIdNumber ->
            binding.userIdNumber.text = nationalIdNumber
        }
        return binding.root
    }


}
```

Comment: There are several ways to persist data (make it outlast the application session). The best one for you will depend on your use case. For the example above where there are just a few Strings to store, I would use SharedPreferences. There are enough of them that I would lean toward creating a class to represent all the form data, and using Gson to convert it to a single String to persist. [Read about data storage here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage). This question is too open-ended to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, because there are so many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Google Room DB library.
Easy store objects.